# Removing hyperlinks in captions from text

Tags: vba, ms-word, hyperlink, caption

I'm trying to remove all captions within a specific range (Page 4 until the end of the document).
I would like to remove only the hyperlink and not the text itself.

For example:
[Some text here](https://edition.cnn.com/) -> Some text here
after removing the hyperlink caption.

I tried:

```vb
Sub removeCaptions()

    Dim rgePages As Range

    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=4
    Set rgePages = Selection.Range
    lastPage = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages.Count
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=lastPage
    rgePages.End = Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.End

    With rgePages.Select

        If Range.Style = "Caption" Then
            Range.Delete
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

I only get the range without removing the captions.

Comment: It is unusual to have hyperlinks in Captions themselves. This cannot be done when inserting Captions using the Insert Caption tool in Word. The hyperlinks have to be added after-the-fact. Are you perhaps referring to hyperlinks to the Captions?

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Format = True
    .Forward = True
    .Style = wdStyleCaption
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    If .Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) > 3 Then .Fields.Unlink
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks great but after running the macro I noticed that the Hyperlinks haven't been removed. (Checked after page 3)

Comment: To resolve the issue you need to press Ctrl + A and then Ctrl + Shift + F9. the thing is that I would like to get the result by the macro.

Comment: Also, it might be important to mention that most of the links refer to other texts in the document itself.

Comment: «after running the macro I noticed that the Hyperlinks haven't been removed» No hyperlinks in a paragraph to which the Caption Style has been applied after page 3 will survive the macro I posted. The hyperlink formatting is not removed, however, as you didn't ask for that.